# How to remove the @api public property in an isExposed true lwc component, which is not in manged release package but exists in next beta version

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have released a managed package(1GP) with a lwc component by having it as `isExposed` to true. Furthermore, we have released a **beta version** by adding a public `@api` property in that lwc component. Now we are trying to remove the public property for releasing another beta version for some reasons..Salesforce is throwing a following error message

"lwc/test/test.js-meta.xml: You can’t remove the following public properties: testVar, because the component is part of a managed package."

Please share any of your thoughts regarding it.

Comment: Interesting. Is this happening during deployment to the packaging org or during version upload?

Comment: @PhilW, Thanks for your response. This error occurs during code deployment.

Comment: This makes me wonder if there is an undocumented limitation similar to custom metadata type picklist field handling (though this latter is [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm&type=5) where you cannot delete or deactivate picklist entries added to a packaging org, even if they have never been packaged themselves). I suggest you raise a case with Salesforce Support.

Comment: @PhilW, this is may be a Salesforce bug. [Reference](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdknvUAB/delete-non-packaged-api-variables-from-managed-lwc-components)

Comment: I would raise a support case and ask for official confirmation this is a bug, and if not request a reference to where this limitation is documented.

Comment: @PhilW, Thanks.